# Aggregation Unwind Document Keys as New Documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I am having some problems in altering the schema I am using for a time series database I have constructed using Mongo DB. Currently, I have records like the one shown below:

```
{
    "_id" : 20,
    "name" : "Bob,
    "location" : "London",
    "01/01/1993" : {
         "height" : "110cm",
         "weight" : "60kg",
    },
   "02/01/1993" : {
         "height" : "112cm",
         "weight" : "61kg",
    }
```

}

I wish to use the aggregation framework to create several records for each "person", one for each "time-value" subdocument in the original record:

```
 {
    "_id" : 20,
    "name" : "Bob,
    "date" : "01/01/1993"
    "location" : "London",
    "height" : "110cm",
    "weight" : "60kg",
 },

 {
    "_id" : 20,
    "name" : "Bob,
    "date" : "02/01/1993"
    "location" : "London",
    "height" : "112cm",
    "weight" : "61kg",
 }
```

The new scheme should be much more efficient when adding a large number of time series values to each record and I shouldn't run into a max document size error!

Any help on how to do this using the Mongo DB aggregation pipeline would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst there are functions in modern releases of the Aggregation Framework that can allow you to do this sort of thing, mileage may vary to whether it is actually the best solution for this.

In essence you can create an array of entries comprised of the document keys "which do not include" the other top level keys which would then be included in the document. That array can then be processed with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and the whole result reshaped into new documents:

```
db.getCollection('input').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "location": 1,
    "data": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
        "as": "d",
        "cond": {
          "$not": { "$in": [ "$$d.k", ["_id","name","location"] ] }    
        }
      }  
    }  
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {  
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [  
          [{ "k": "id", "v": "$_id" },
           { "k": "name", "v": "$name" },
           { "k": "location", "v": "$location" },
           { "k": "date", "v": "$data.k" }],
          { "$objectToArray": "$data.v" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "output" }
])
```

or alternately do all the reshaping in the initial [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) within the array elements produced:

```
db.getCollection('input').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "data": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "as": "d",
            "cond": {
              "$not": { "$in": [ "$$d.k", ["_id", "name", "location"] ] }    
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "d",
        "in": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              { "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                "as": "r",
                "cond": { "$in": [ "$$r.k", ["_id", "name", "location"] ] }
              }},
              [{ "k": "date", "v": "$$d.k" }],
              { "$objectToArray": "$$d.v" }
            ]   
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } },
  { "$out": "output" }
])
```

So you use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in order to make an array from the keys which actually contain the data points for each date.

After [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) we basically apply [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) on a set of named keys in the "array format" in order to construct the `newRoot` for [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and then write to the new collection, as one new document for each data key using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

That may only get you part of the way though, as you really should change the `"date"`data to a BSON Date. It takes a lot less storage space, and is easier to query as well.

```
var updates = [];
db.getCollection('output').find().forEach( d => {
  updates.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": d._id },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "date": new Date(
            Date.UTC.apply(null,
              d.date.split('/')
                .reverse().map((e,i) => (i == 1) ? parseInt(e)-1: parseInt(e) )
            )
          )
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if ( updates.length >= 500 ) {
    db.getCollection('output').bulkWrite(updates);
    updates = [];
  }
})

if ( updates.length != 0 ) {
  db.getCollection('output').bulkWrite(updates);
  updates = [];
}
```

Of course, if your MongoDB server lacks those aggregation features then you are better off just writing the output to a new collection by iterating the loop in the first place:

```
var output = [];

db.getCollection('input').find().forEach( d => {
  output = [
    ...output,
    ...Object.keys(d)
      .filter(k => ['_id','name','location'].indexOf(k) === -1)
      .map(k => Object.assign(
        { 
          id: d._id,
          name: d.name,
          location: d.location,
          date: new Date(
            Date.UTC.apply(null,
              k.split('/')
                .reverse().map((e,i) => (i == 1) ? parseInt(e)-1: parseInt(e) )
            )
          )
        },
        d[k]
      ))
  ];

  if ( output.length >= 500 ) {
    db.getCollection('output').insertMany(output);
    output = [];    
  }
})

if ( output.length != 0 ) {
  db.getCollection('output').insertMany(output); 
  output = [];
}
```

In either of those cases we want to apply [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to the reversed string elements from the existing "string" based date and get a value than can be cast into a BSON Date.

The aggregation framework itself **does not allow casting of types** so the **only** solution for that part ( and it is a necessary part ) is to actually loop and update, but using the forms at least makes it efficient to loop and update.

Either case gives you the same end output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599275b1e38f41729f1d64fe"),
    "id" : 20.0,
    "name" : "Bob",
    "location" : "London",
    "date" : ISODate("1993-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "height" : "110cm",
    "weight" : "60kg"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599275b1e38f41729f1d64ff"),
    "id" : 20.0,
    "name" : "Bob",
    "location" : "London",
    "date" : ISODate("1993-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "height" : "112cm",
    "weight" : "61kg"
}
```

Comment: Great answer. In the first part (aggregation pipeline) you use the following: "$not": { "$in": [ "$$d.k", ["_id","name","location"] ] } . What does the $$d.k refer to? I understand this is used to 'skip' the object to array command for the _id , name and location fields but unsure of the exact methodology!

Comment: I just can't seem to find a reference to 'k' in the code preceding this statement

Comment: @Ctrp You need to look at the documentation links provided in the answer, and particularly at `$objectToArray`. What is does is takes every "key" and "value" of the input "object" and produces an "array" with entries like `[ { "k" : "01/01/1993", "v" : { "height" : "110cm", "weight" : "60kg" } }, ]`. So that is what the `k` and `v` mean throughout the listing.